# DAX Measure with multiple columns from different related tables in filter expression

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerpivot

I need help with DAX Measure. I have 3 tables Builds, Dynamic, Environments. They are all related with each other. I have created a report with Builds slicer from Builds table and a table chart with the following columns:

- BUILD[Environments Table]
- Target Build[Dynamic Table]
- State[Environements Table]
- EnvironmentID[Environments Table]

Now I want to create a measure to calculate count of  In Progress Environments where Build = selected build in slicer or target build = selected build in slicer.

Can someone please help me with the correct formula. Thanks!

I came up with the below formula:

```
InprogressEnvironments = 
VAR SelectedSlicerValue = SELECTEDVALUE(Builds[Build])
RETURN
  VAR CountEnvs =
    CALCULATE (
      DISTINCTCOUNT ( 'vwEnvironments'[EnvironmentID] ),
      OR (
        'vwEnvironments'[Build] = SelectedSlicerValue,
        vwDynamic[TARGETBUILD] = SelectedSlicerValue
      ),
      'vwEnvironments'[State] = "In Progress"
    )
  RETURN
    CountEnvs
```

However, this measure is returning the following error: The expression contains multiple columns, but only a single column can be used in a True/False expression that is used as a table filter expression.

Comment: The error is based on your `OR` function. Simple predicates to `CALCULATE` can only refer to a single column. Would you please provide a sample of your data and model, as well as expected output based on that sample? It's impossible for us to infer these things. Please see [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) on producing a minimal working example.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what the relationship between the two table is but something like this may work:

```
InprogressEnvironments =
VAR SelectedSlicerValue =
    SELECTEDVALUE ( Builds[Build] )
VAR CountEnvs =
    CALCULATE (
        DISTINCTCOUNT ( 'vwEnvironments'[EnvironmentID] ),
        'vwEnvironments'[State] = "In Progress",
        'vwEnvironments'[Build] = SelectedSlicerValue
            || RELATED ( 'vwDynamic'[TARGETBUILD] ) = SelectedSlicerValue
    )
RETURN
    CountEnvs
```

Comment: That will hit the same error. Your third arg to `CALCULATE` is `'vwEnvironments'[Build] = SelectedSlicerValue || RELATED ( vwDynamic'[TARGETBUILD] ) = SelectedSlicerValue`. Simple predicates to `CALCULATE` cannot reference multiple columns. The correct answer will depend on what the relationships are, as you've noted. In a typical star schema, I'd write it as `CALCULATE ( ..., FILTER ( GROUPBY ( 'Fact', 'Dim1'[Field], 'Dim2'[Field] ), 'Dim1'[Field] = <value> || 'Dim2'[Field] = <value> ) )`. Table-valued args to `CALCULATE` can be as complex as you want.

Comment: I can see that in my .pbix, tables are connected to each other using the below shown relationships.
 
Build ---> vwEnvironments (one to Many) ON (Builds.build = vwEnvironments.Build)
vwEnvironments <--> Dynamic (Many to One) ON (vwEnvironments.RunID = Dynamic.RunID)